# Is this form of the Duffing equation correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

> A complex dynamical system that describes a steel beam deflected toward two magnets is the Duffing equation:
>   \begin{aligned}
>  \frac{\text d x}{\text d t} &= y \\
>  \frac{\text d y}{\text d t} &= -y + rx - x^3
> \end{aligned}
>   where $r$ is a control parameter.

I'm looking through a problem sheet and the form for the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) appears to be wrong?

I'm trying to find stationary solutions for the system and find bifurcations and so on. The control parameter $r$ should be in front of the $y$ term according to the sources I have seen? With this form I can't get a solution that seems reasonable. Could anyone tell me if this is indeed a mistake?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DuffingDifferentialEquation.html. All 3 terms on the RHS of $\dot y$ can have coefficients, so I think it is impossible to say which is the control parameter in this question. There does not appear to be any physics involved here : I  think your question would be more appropriate on Mathematics SE.

Comment: Maybe the problem sheet forgot the time-varying input term? Or more likely, you are supposed to find the bifurcations of this simpler system before tackling the complex one?

Answer (score 1):

Injecting the first equation in the second one, we get
$$
\ddot{x} + \dot{x} - rx + x^3 = 0 \, ,
$$
which is the equation of a free (unforced) Duffing oscillator. Here, the control parameter $r$ is defined as the linear part of the stiffness.

The equilibrium points of the system satisfy $x \left(x^2 - r\right) = 0$, i.e. $x=0$ or $x = \pm\sqrt{r}$. The Jacobian matrix of the system is
$$
J(x) =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
r - 3x^2 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Evaluated at the origin, we have the eigenvalues
$$
\text{Sp}\, J(0) = \left\lbrace -\frac{\sqrt{1+4r} + 1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{1+4r} - 1}{2} \right\rbrace .
$$
If $r > 0$, one eigenvalue is strictly positive, and the origin is unstable. Otherwise, if $r<0$, the origin is asymptotically stable (both eigenvalues have negative real parts).
Evaluated at the other equilibrium values, we have for $r>0$,
$$
\text{Sp}\, J(\pm\sqrt{r}) = \left\lbrace -\frac{\sqrt{1-8r} + 1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{1-8r} - 1}{2} \right\rbrace .
$$
A similar stability analysis can be performed which shows that both equilibrium points are asymptotically stable. Here is a view of the bifurcation diagram:

[image: Bifurcation Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia version is
$$\ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} + \alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma \cos (\omega t).$$
Obviously, for your task $γ=0$. Now set (assuming $δ>0$)
$$
x(t)=c\,u(δt),~ \dot x =cδ\,\dot u(δt),~\ddot{x}(t)=cδ^2\,\ddot u(δt)
$$
Inserting one gets
$$
δ^2\,\ddot u(δt)+δ^2\,\dot u(δt)+α\,u(δt)+c^2β\,u(δt)^3=0
$$
so that setting $s=δt$, $c=δ/\sqrtβ$, $r=-α/δ^2$ one gets the normal form
$$
\ddot u(s)+\dot u(s)-r\,u(s)+u(s)^3=0
$$
which is used in the question.

---

One could also change the scaling in time and space to get the new parameters have $α=\pm 1$, $β=1$, then the remaining characteristic parameter is $δ$. Set $x(t)=c\,u(\sqrt{|α|}t)$, $s=\sqrt{|α|}t$
$$
|α|\,\ddot u(s)+\sqrt{|α|}δ\,\dot u(s)+α\,u(s)+c^2β\,u(s)^3=0
$$
now set $c=\sqrt{\frac{|α|}β}$, $\kappa=\fracδ{\sqrt{|α|}}$ to get the normal form
$$
\ddot u(s)+κ\,\dot u(s)+\text{sign}(α)\,u(s)+u(s)^3=0
$$
which is what you were expecting from your other source.